# Sharelatex doesn't recognize relative path of bib files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, sharelatex

I am having problems with sharelatex trying to use a list of bib files which are in a different directory from the one of the main tex file. My file structure is:

```
- tex_folder
    * tex_file
- bib_folder
    * bib_file1
    * bib_file2
```

This is the tex_file

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \title{test}
    \author{ }
    \date{October 2016}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \section{Introduction}
    testing my bibliography \cite{ref1}

   \bibliographystyle{plain}
   \bibliography{../bib_folder/bib_file1, ../bib_folder/bib_file2}

    \end{document}
```

and this bib_file1.bib:

```
    @ARTICLE{ref1,
    author = {author_list},
    title = {nice_title},
    journal = {J. of journal},
    year = {2010}
    }
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
    You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.


    BibTeX I couldn't open database file ../bib_folder/bib_file1}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a *complete* example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows your problem. Moreover, explain *why* it doesn't work. Any error messages? Which programs to you use: bibtex, biber? With this sparse information it is hard to guess what went wrong.  When I add a minimal frame such that it compiles, I don't get errors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I don't get errors either when I do not use sharelatex.. that's why I thought sharelatex might have problems with relative paths.

Comment: You have just added the tag `biblatex`, but `\bibliographystyle` doesn't look like `biblatex`. Therefore provide a complete document.

Comment: Well, we want to see exactly such a simple example. Add the code to your posting using the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/333806/edit).

Comment: you are still just showing fragments, is the path to the document shown as `./tex_file.tex` or `tex_folder/tex_file.tex` at the start of the log?

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice the line in the log. It's tex_folder/tex_file.tex

Comment: so you want `\bibliography{bib_folder/bib_file1, bib_folder/bib_file2}` without the `../`

Comment: true.. makes sense... I hadn't thought of it! Thanks a lot and sorry for the not good presentation of my question... it was my first post.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wanna answer?

Comment: n@Johannes_B  close as typo solved in comment

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it was just a  typo in the file path and already solved in comments.